# transform feedback skips 3 of 4-element vec3 array

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I have a geometry shader output like this:

```
out vec3 out_a[4];
out vec3 out_c[4];
out vec3 out_b;
out int out_d;
```

after shader compilation, before linking, I set:

```
GLchar *vars[5] = { "gl_Position","out_a","out_b","out_c","out_d" };

glTransformFeedbackVaryings(pgm,5,vars,GL_INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS);
```

Transform feedback is capturing `out_a` (which is a vec3[4]) as a single vec3, while `out_c` (which is also a vec3[4]) is correctly captured as a `12 x GL_FLOAT` sequence.

Transform feedback object, vbo/vao and buffer objects are ok. The problem is that the transform feedback is capturing only the first of a 4 element array (but the other 4 element array is captured right)

Has anyone ever seen such behavior? Changing the order of the captured varyings does not change anything, `out_a` (and only that) is always captured as a single vec3.

`glGetTransformFeedbackVaryings` for `out_a` correctly reports `4 x GL_FLOAT_VEC3` (and the values for the other outputs are right as well), but `out_a` is still a single vec3 in the buffer object.

Comment: Could it be that you only set `out_a[0]` in your shader code and don't use the other indexes?

Comment: `out_a` is set in a `for(int a=0;a<4;a++)` loop, together with `out_c`, just before geometry exit

Comment: a plain driver bug IMHO, Im on a GeForce GT 330M with the latest 319.23